# Angular Material Table - Move vertical scrollbar into table body

Tags: angular, html-table, angular-material, scrollbar

I have an angular project and rely on angular material.

I want to move the vertical scrollbar into tbody. Previously like this:
[V-Scrollbar for full table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhL9L.png)

I want it could be like this: [V-Scrollbar in tbody](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laVXx.png)

I had tried couples of method but all failed.

This is the best I can do:[V-Scrollbar in tbody but destroy style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJH1Z.png)

But you can see, it totally destroy the layout.

Please give me some suggestions or good ideas. Thank you!

PS: I had created a demo project here: https://github.com/JoeyLi-1/angularMaterialExample

Comment: Why no just use [sticky headers](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-sticky-columns)? All the ways of moving scrollbar to the tbody will be hacky and will break some properties of the table.

Comment: @TotallyNewb Already use sticky headers. However, thank you for the reply!